# <div> background got cut

Tags: html, css

I wanna highlight some lines in a `<div>`.
Some lines are longer than the width of the `<div>`, so I use `<div style="overflow:scroll;">`.
However, when I scroll to the right, the highlighted background is cut at the right edge, so text longer than the `<div>`'s width has no background. 
[image]

```
<style>
.a { background-color:red; }
.b { background-color:yellow; }
</style>
<div style="overflow:scroll;width:49%;height:100%;border:1px solid silver;white-space:nowrap;">
<pre>
<div class="a">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
dffdgfdsgfg</div>
<div class="b">asdsad</div>
</pre>
</div>
```

Can anyone fix this?

Comment: but i don't wanna break them apart. i wanna keep them in one line

Comment: also i've tried to put my content in an <iframe>, but still not working...

Answer (score 3):

remove white-space:nowrap;

and add `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be related to wordwrap: this is a good article that explains its use: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

hope it helps,